# What do time and latency mean in the webkit inspector?

Tags: performance, webkit

What do time and latency mean in the context of the webkit inspector?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Time is total duration, from the start of the request to the receipt
>   of the final byte in the response. Latency is the time to load the
>   first byte in the response.

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network

Comment: That makes sense. So time includes the time it takes Chrome to process the html, js, css, etc?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the time is the overall time it takes to run the literal website code added with the latency while the latency is the delay received while sending said code information across the internet.

Comment: Close, latency is the delay in time it took in traveling across the internet.

Comment: Right but how does the webkit inspector track that if it is running it straight through the browser and monitoring it. That is, unless the webkit inspector runs the code live on the internet through a server.

Comment: Because that information is contained in TCP packets. I don't know the exact details, but there's extra information attached to the data being transferred back and forth which can be used by the browser to track latency.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense because that is the usual definition of latency in terms of the networking and internet connections.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by "run the literal website code"? Do you mean processing/parsing the html/js/css?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Compiling (processing/parsing) then running the code and seeing how much time it takes to initialize it when it is accessed from a point from the internet.

Comment: Yeah and then the timer checks how much time said code takes to be accessed/initialized from a point across the internet.